# Remove or prevent duplicate rows created when nesting arrays

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table where I'm using `ARRAY_AGG` on some of the columns but it makes the rows no longer unique.

| date | id | type | topic_id | topic_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-12 | abc | type1 | 123 | topic1 |
| 2022-12-12 | abc | type1 | 456 | topic2 |

When the topic info is put into a struct using `ARRAY_AGG`, we get the following using the code below:

| date | id | type | topic.topic_id | topic.topic_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-12 | abc | type1 | 123 | topic1 |
|  |  |  | 456 | topic2 |
| 2022-12-12 | abc | type1 | 123 | topic1 |
|  |  |  | 456 | topic2 |

```
select 
  date,
  id,
  type,
  array_agg (
    struct (
      topic_id,
      topic_name,
    )
  ) as topic
from table
group by 1, 2, 3
```

Is there a way to drop one of these rows either before or after the nesting to get the following result?

| date | id | type | topic.topic_id | topic.topic_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-12 | abc | type1 | 123 | topic1 |
|  |  |  | 456 | topic2 |

Comment: How your expected output differ from the two outputs you've shown in your post?

Comment: Your query has no problem and will return only 1 row with your sample table. (just remove trailing comma in `topic_name,`.